# Previous or next element in array based on string "direction"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make function that will return next or previous item in array, based on parameter "direction".
For example I have array = ['ferrari', 'bmw', 'merc', 'bugatti'] and I want my my function to return 'bugatti' IF currentPointer = 'ferrari' and direction = 'left'

nextPrev(array,direction,currentPointer)

In php we have function next() which moves the internal pointer ... but I don't know how to do it in javascript ...

Comment: Try with indexOf method, you can find current key easily....E.g. this is just a start, but you will get the idea... http://jsfiddle.net/u37y31h2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Something like this.**

Using the numerical locations of the array and conditionally cycle through:

```js
var array = ['ferrari', 'bmw', 'merc', 'bugatti'];

var returnedElement = nextPrev(array, "left", "ferrari");

// Show Returned Value (Console)
console.log(returnedElement);

function nextPrev(array, direction, currentPointer) {
  var arraySize = array.length - 1;
  var currentIndex = array.indexOf(currentPointer);

  if (direction === "left") {

    // Decrease array by one
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
      // Return Previous (Max Array)
      return array[arraySize]

    } else {
      return array[currentIndex - 1]
    }

  } else if (direction === "right") {

    // Increase array by one
    if (currentIndex == arraySize) {

      // Go to zero position
      return array[0]

    } else {
      return array[currentIndex + 1]
    }

  } else {
    console.log("Use either 'left' or 'right'");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would be:

```
function nextPrev(array, direction, currentPointer) {
    var index = array.indexOf(currentPointer);
    if (direction=="left") {
        return array[index == 0 ? array.length-1 : index-1];
    } else if (direction=="right") {
        return array[index == array.length-1 ? 0 : index+1];
    } else {
        // default action or throw error
    }
}
```

You can reorganize this a bit:

```
function nextPrev(array, direction, currentPointer) {
    var index = array.indexOf(currentPointer);
    var len = array.length;
    if (direction=="left") {
        index--;
    } else if (direction=="right") {
        index++
    } else {
        // default action or throw error
    }
        return array[(index + len) % len];
}
```

You might want to add a check that `array.indexOf` returns a valid index (in case `currentPointer` contains something not in `array`).

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
function makeDirectionalIterator(array){
    var currIndex = 0;

    return {
       nextPrev: function(direction){
           if(direction === 'left') {
              return currIndex < array.length-1 ?
                 {value: array[++currIndex], done: false} :
                 {done: true};
           }
           else {
              return currIndex > 0 ?
                 {value: array[--currIndex], done: false} :
                 {done: true};
           }
       },

       current: function() {
           return { value: array[currIndex] };
       }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like the following

```
var itr = makeDirectionalIterator(array);
itr.current().value;
itr.nextPrev('left').value;
itr.nextPrev('left').done;
```